# How to deal with working on one project on different machines (paths)?

Tags: python, github, import, path, project

This is my first time coding a "project" (something more than solving exercises in single files). A number of my .py files have variables imported from a specific path. I also have a main "Run" file where I import things I've written in other files and execute the project as a whole.

Recently I've started working on this project on several different machines (home, work, laptop etc) and have just started learning how to use GitHub.

My question is, how do I deal with the fact that every time I open up my code on a different machine I need to go around changing all the paths to fit the new machine, and then change them back again when I'm home? I started writing a Run file for each location I work at so that my sys.path commands are ok with that machine, but it doesn't solve the problem of my other modules importing variables from specific paths that vary from machine to machine. Is there a way round this or is the problem in how I'm setting up the project itself?

In an ideal world it would all just work without me having to change something before I run, depending on the machine I'm working on, but I don't know if that's possible.

My current thoughts are whether there is some command I'm not aware of that can set variables inside a .py file from my main Run.py file - that way I can just have a run file for each machine.

Any suggestions are gladly taken! Whatever it is, it must be better than commenting back in the correct file path each time I open it on a different machine!

Answer (score 0):

You should always use relative paths, not static which I assume you have got.
Assuming your in an index file and you need to access images folder, you probably have something like `/users/username/project/images/image.png`

Instead you want something like `../images/image.png`, this tells your index file to go backwards one folder to say the root of the project, then proceed into our images folder etc.

Relative paths mean you create a path from where your file exists, and not an entire path from ground up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify all your setting that are hardcoded in your project, and make them relative to your current workspace. This is a common problem.

Also if you are using python, make sure that you do not hardcode the path to files in string, but instead that you use the proper system api:

```
os.path.join('file','to','your','ressource')
```

that will be computed differently if you are on unix or windows.